# Jenkins slaves go offline or hang when archiving artifacts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In the job post build action, am archiving the artifacts. 90% of the time, when the jenkins job reaches this step, the slave on which it is running hangs (or) goes offline (or) the job hangs and if I kill the job it throws a "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error.

Am running Jenkins ver 1.560.

Has anyone seen this or is aware of a fix for this? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running into https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22734 which started in version 1.560 and will be fixed in 1.563.

It's always a good idea to browse the [Jenkins change log](http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog), especially the Community Ratings section, when you install a new version.

Comment: Thanks gareth. I am updating to 1.563 SNAPSHOT version to see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever Hudson master will run out of space, slaves will disconnect and will have to be restarted.

You need to check Hudson master box and see how much space is allocated to the drive where hudson is running.

Another thing to note is that even if a job is running on slave, artifacts are archived always on master. So space allocation on master should be done properly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue with 1.560v of Jenkins. Right now I have disabled the archiving of the maven artifacts from the "Build" section.
[image: Screen shot for disabling maven artifact archiving]